# Eclipse: Build variable as string in C code

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, preprocessor, iar

I try to use a build variable as a string in my C preprocessor code to make a compiler switch.

**Build variable:**
VER: A

**Preprocessor/Defined Symbol:**
`VER=${VER}`

Code:

```
#if VER == 'A'
#define VERSION (1)
#endif
```

The expression is always false.
The same syntax is working with numbers given in the build variable but I would need to use strings in the same way. What would be the way to do it?

IDE: Eclipse

Compiler: IAR

Comment: Actually what does "Build variable: VER: A" even mean? Is this some Eclipse gunk? In case this is passed along to gcc as `gcc -DVER=A` rather than `gcc -DVER='A'` then that would be the problem. Eclipse in general is a problem generator, so I'd recommend to stay clear of it.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, this can be the problem. Is it possible to pass it like -DVER='A' ?

Comment: If Eclipse works anything like command prompts (which I wouldn't assume), you can try `-DVER="'A'"`. Or rather just `"'A'"`. Or better yet ditch Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known phenomenon: pre-processor tokens which are not found are evaluated by `#if` as zero. Therefore rugged code ought to be written along the lines of this:

```
#if defined(VER) && VER == 'A'
```

Or if you want a compiler error:

```
#ifndef VER
  #error VER not defined!
#elif VER == 'A'
  #define VERSION (1)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are escaping the text as a character. So `'A'` will be evaluate to the value 65 (the ASCII number of the uppercase letter A). You can verify this by defining your build variable `VER` to be the value 65.

If you want to compare a (simple) string, you should just remove the quotes:

```c
#if VER == A
#define VERSION 1
#endif
```